# Remove common item in list of lists based on different index position

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have a list of lists, and I want to remove all the items after `'d'`, and I want to do that based on the index location of `'d'` in both lists, how would I do that if the index location of `'d'` is different in each list.

Is there a better way than indexing?

```
ab_list = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'d','e', 'f'], ['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
loc=[]
for i in ab_list:
    loc.append(i.index('d'))
print(loc)

# output is [3, 1]

for i in ab_list:
    for l in loc:
        ab_list_keep=(i[0:l])
        print(ab_list_keep)
## output is 
#['a', 'b', 'c']
#['a']
#['a', 'd', 'e']
#['a']
```

The first two lines of the output is what I'd want, but making a list out of the index locations of `'d'` doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's built in [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) method is designed for cases like this one:

```
import itertools
ab_list = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'d','e', 'f'],['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
print([list(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i != "d", sublist)) for sublist in ab_list])
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering with lambda i: i != "d", is it a function within lambda that it would exclude 'e' and 'f' in the list; I just assumed != d would include 'e' and 'f'

Comment: @evc Your assumption is correct. However, `takewhile` will discard the rest of the iterator (sublist, in this case) once the condition fails (that is, after the first `'d'`).

Comment: Thanks for introducing itertools.takewhile !

Comment: You are welcome. Also take a look at `dropwhile` which is the reverse (i.e. it discards the elements of the iterator until the condition is met).